# How can I set context param in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, context-param

When user logged in I will read user preferences from database and set the primefaces theme name. My application is a springboot application and using primefaces v7. I don't have a web.xml file. I need to do the equivalent of the following:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{userPreferencesBean.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I tired to add different properties to application.properties file.

I added this line to application.properties file:

```
primefaces.THEME=#{userPreferencesBean.theme}
```

I also tried to add this one:

```
spring.primefaces.theme=#{userPreferencesBean.theme}
```

even I tried this one and nothing changed:

```
spring.primefaces.theme=glass-x
```

Comment: primefaces config params are managed via the servlet context / web.xml, thats called servlet context parameters. Did you check how to set servlet context params with spring boot?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved my problem by adding the line server.servlet.context-parameters.primefaces.THEME=#{userPreferencesBean.theme} to the application.properties file as you mentioned.